# New-Cluster : Cannot convert 'IP' to the type 'System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection' required by parameter 'StaticAddress'

Tags: powershell

I am creating the cluster with the PowerShell scripting

```
New-Cluster -Name $Clustername -Node $Hostname -StaticAddress $ClusterIP
```

But when it comes to execute the command it gives the below error

> New-Cluster : Cannot convert '192.168.155.196' to the type 'System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection' required by parameter 'StaticAddress'. Unable to cast object of type  'System.Net.IPAddress' to type 'System.String'

Comment: What if you put double quotes around $clusterIP

Comment: Could you try `[string[]]'192.168.155.196'` to force the address into a string collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error shows `$ClusterIP` is a `[System.Net.IPAddress]` object. Use its `ToString()` method instead:

```
New-Cluster -Name $Clustername -Node $Hostname -StaticAddress $ClusterIP.ToString()
```